# How can I retrieve Similar Orders In Mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

i need a query that should first look the oldest order which has status 0 (zero). and retrieves all the similar orders of that kind(matches exact total qty, itemSku and number of distinct items ordered).

```
***OrdersTable***
ID    OrderNumber    CustomerId    Status    created_at
1     123456         1             0         2018-01-01 
2     234567         1             0         2018-01-02
3     345678         1             0         2018-01-03
4     456789         1             0         2018-01-04   

***PurchasedProductsTable***
OrderId     itemSku     Qty
1           1000001     1
1           1000002     2
2           1000001     3
3           1000001     1
3           1000002     2
4           1000001     3
```

In the above table the query should first look at the oldest (created_at ASC) order (i.e with Id 1) having status 0 (in order table). and along with that order it should retrieves all the other orders that matches the same itemSku, qty and total distinct items count (in purchasedProducts table).

here order 1 and 3 matches the same itemSKu (1000001 and 1000002) and qty ( 1 and 2) and both have (2) distinct items count respectively so order 1 and 3 should be retrived at first.and when i marked order 1 and 3 as shipped (i.e chang status to 2).

and if i run query again it should retrive similar oders. now order 2 and 4 as order 2 and 4 are similar orders. (have same itemSkus (1000001, Qty (3) and distinct items count (1)).

please help thanks

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @kojow yeah its working though :)) but it only dont works when the same itemSku are add multiple times in same order :)

Answer (score 1):

You have to go trough your tables two times :)

Something like this :

```
SELECT DISTINCT O2.ID
FROM OrdersTable O1
INNER JOIN PurchasedProductsTable P1 ON O1.ID = P1.OrderId
INNER JOIN PurchasedProductsTable P2 ON P1.itemSku = P2.itemSku 
  AND P1.Qty = P2.Qty 
INNER JOIN OrdersTable O2 ON O2.ID = P2.OrderId
WHERE O1.ID = 
        (SELECT ID FROM OrdersTable WHERE Status = 0 
              ORDER BY created_at ASC LIMIT 1)
  AND (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM PurchasedProductsTable WHERE OrderId = O1.ID)
     = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM PurchasedProductsTable WHERE OrderId = O2.ID)
ORDER BY O2.ID ASC;
```

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/65t9GgSfqMpzNVgnrJp2TR/2

Comment: when i change the Qty in line 30 ( ('3', '1000002', '2') to  ('3', '1000002', '3') ) it still retrive order id 3 in the list. which is not supposed to be like. it should only show ID 1

Answer (score 0):

You can get the earliest order via a limit and ordered by the date.
Then you can left join to get that order and any other order that at least has the same items.

Then once you have those order id's from the sub-query result, you can get the order details.

```
SELECT o.*
FROM
(
  SELECT DISTINCT ord2.ID as OrderId
  FROM 
  (
     SELECT ID, CustomerId, Status
     FROM OrdersTable
     WHERE Status = 0
     ORDER BY created_at
     LIMIT 1
  ) AS ord1
  JOIN PurchasedProductsTable AS pprod1
    ON pprod1.OrderId = ord1.ID
  LEFT JOIN OrdersTable ord2
    ON ord2.CustomerId = ord1.CustomerId
   AND ord2.Status = ord1.Status
  LEFT JOIN PurchasedProductsTable pprod2
    ON pprod2.OrderId = ord2.ID
   AND pprod2.itemSku = pprod1.itemSku
   AND pprod2.Qty = pprod1.Qty
  GROUP BY ord1.CustomerId, ord1.ID, ord2.ID
  HAVING COUNT(pprod1.itemSku) = COUNT(pprod2.itemSku)
) q
JOIN OrdersTable AS o ON o.ID = q.OrderId;
```

Test on *RexTester [here](https://rextester.com/EWL31435)*

Comment: when i change the order status to 1 of ID 1 and ID 2 , it does not show anything . but it should retrive ID 3 :)

Comment: So you want to show the earliest order with status 0 even when there's no matching other order with the same skuItems.

Comment: yeah that exactly what i needed :) it will go from up to down if it has other matching orders it will get all others otherwise will return that only. and if no order are with status 0 then only it dont show anything :)

Comment: @imDevD Updated.  But do note that the current query will get the earliest order, and orders with the same items. But those other orders could have more items than the earliest.